# Symfony ResetType: reset dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, forms, filter, reset

I added a "Reset Filter" button and it's perfectly doing what it promised, so whenever it's clicked, all the selected filters are reset. 
However, there's one thing that's still bothering me, concering dropdowns I use for filtering. When something is selected in that dropdown and I hit the "reset" button, the dropdown still shows the selected values. Only when opening the dropdown, I see that there is actually nothing selected. [image: issue]
I added the following screenshot, to show what I mean. That's the situation AFTER I hit the "Reset filter" button, so the resetting of the dropdown worked (no value is selected) but it's still displaying "BR" as selected.. And if I would now select another value of that dropdown (e.g. CA) and then applied the filters both (BR and CA) would be selected.. 
So what I thought is, that I need an ajax that's reloading the page after I clicked "Reset filter"? or is there a javascript that's handling the reset? I'm kind of lost.

Btw. I'm using the bootstrap-multiselect.js for that dropdown!

```
      $('#document_filter_markets').multiselect({
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true, includeSelectAllOption: true, nonSelectedText: 'Select Markets',
    maxHeight: 200
  });
```

Any ideas how to clear everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer myself.

I added a reset-button:

```
  <input type="reset" id="resetter" class="btn-primary btn btn-xs" value="Reset All"/>
```

and then added some javascript to that button to uncheck everything and then refresh the dropdown:

```
    $("#resetter").click(function () {      
    $('option', $('#document_filter_markets')).each(function(element) {
    $(this).removeAttr('selected').prop('selected', false);
      });
      $("#document_filter_markets").multiselect('refresh');
});
```

Hope it helps!